# CiviCRM: Error when sending mail- emails not getting to all recipients

Tags: civicrm

since mid-August I've seen a sharp drop in the # of people who are opening our e-newsletters, and wonder if the error below is related, what it means, and whether there's a solution? I'm not getting bounced emails, and the people I've checked with have said the messages aren't going into their spam; the emails aren't reaching some mailboxes at all. I tried to look at the source mentioned in the trace, but I couldn't figure out anything from it.

```
-----------------------------ERROR MESSAGE IN LOG-------------------------------------
Sep 17 13:56:26  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site adminstrator for assistance.<br /><br />Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.<br /><br />Error type: Could not find a valid session key.

[code] => 
)

Sep 17 13:56:26  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(315): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(278): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enable...")
#2 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(186): CRM_Core_Controller->key("CRM_Mailing_Controller_Send", TRUE, FALSE)
#3 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Controller/Send.php(41): CRM_Core_Controller->__construct("New Mailing", "null", NULL, FALSE, TRUE)
#4 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(287): CRM_Mailing_Controller_Send->__construct("New Mailing", TRUE, "null", NULL, "false")
#5 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(70): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#6 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#7 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(344): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#8 [internal function](): civicrm_wp_invoke("")
#9 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(505): call_user_func_array("civicrm_wp_invoke", (Array:1))
#10 /home/afaeus/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(212): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#11 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

It makes a big difference whether

1. nobody is getting emails, or
2. fewer people are getting emails.

If it's the latter, and they're not getting them in spam or anything else, you might try looking in your mail log.  On a Debian/Ubuntu machine with Postfix, that's usually /var/log/mail.log.  On other VPS/dedicated setups, it should be someplace similar.  You might find that some servers are rejecting the messages.

You also should us a blacklist search to see if your server is being blacklisted someplace.

Finally, you should know that if your "from" address is a Yahoo or AOL address (or possibly another third-party service), you're likely to get rejected my many providers.  They'll effectively say, "We know Yahoo's servers, and this is coming from someplace else--it must be a scam."

Now, on the other hand, if you have *no* email going out, the CiviCRM error is likely related.  I don't know what could be causing that one, however.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests a few things, none of which would be related to deliverability of the emails.

- People may be clicking on a link in an email or perhaps in a bookmark which includes a session key that is now expired. Search results, and multi-stage actions typically have in the url a key-value pair like qfKey=0fe0c51c4024538bb34d5c84305ffb8a_8786 that is a give-away that it cannot be shared, and will not work if you sign-out from the site.
- As the error description indicates, you may have more than one domain configured for the site, and the session is not being carried from one to other. Check that your CiviCRM base_url is correct both in civicrm.settings.php and through the browser at the following urls:
- See CiviCRM Menu: Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths
- Drupal sites: http:///index.php?q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1
- Joomla 1.5 sites: http:///administrator/index2.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1
  Joomla 1.6 sites: http:///administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1
- Wordpress sites: http:///wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1

NB: Prior to 4.3.3 the WordPress implementation mistakenly drops everything after the domain in its suggestion for a new URL. The default location for a WordPress install relative to docroot would normally mean that the url should be http:///wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/